# How to loop a tune played on keyboard on walk band? Android

Tags: virtual-instrument

I am using walkband Android app for making a tune. But I need a continuous background music to be played while I am playing the main music. How do I play a note and loop it to be played continuously for background tune in walkband app?

Comment: Did you check the manual, or ask the developer?

Comment: Why are you using this app? Initial googling looks like it's made by a single developer who also makes games. There's no support that I can find. Why not use something with a bigger community, and maybe more features?

Comment: @Tetsujin no response from them.

Comment: @AndyBonner Can you suggest any such software with virtual instruments?

Comment: The first thing that occurred to me was GarageBand, but that's not for Android. BandLab seems to be popular. I recommend starting with something simple, and if that doesn't work, moving to something bigger.